# How to Use CWinThread for making worker thread in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I want to know what is the process to use CWinThread derived class as a worker thread in MFC.
The msdn documentation says that CWinthread::InitInstance() or CWinthread::Run() should be used only for UI threads.

So is there a way to create worker threads apart from AfxbeginThread()? I need to have a worker thread class in my code which will store some more information private to it and thus would like to have it derived from CWinThread.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create worker thread without using AfxBeginThread.

You could override the virtual int Run(); function to put your code there and call ExitInstance() at the end of the function to end the thread. To start your thread, you can either make a call to AfxBeginThread, or simply call the CreateThead function on your thread object

```
//First option
CMyThread* pMyThread = (CMyThread*)AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyThread));

//Second option
CMyThread myThread;
myThread.CreateThread();
```

Maybe it's not MFC's official way, but it works!

Comment: The [AfxBeginThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) docs say that the CRuntimeClass should be the RUNTIME_CLASS of an object derived from CWinThread. This seems to be what was asked for.

Comment: Yes that's the first option in my example.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation indicates that the only way to create a "true" MFC worker thread is through `AfxBeginThread()`.  However, you can approximate a worker thread by creating a derived CWinThread object, invoking it, doing all the work in `InitInstance()`, and then terminating the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to derive from CWinThread to store some more information private to the worker thread. The AFX_THREADPROC function pointer version of AfxBeginThread takes a LPVOID argument that can be used to pass in anything. A simple string, a structure full of private information, or even [a pointer to the class that called AfxBeginThread](http://www.flounder.com/workerthreads.htm) (just be careful of synchronization and don't touch the GUI from your worker thread.)

```
// static
UINT TaskingDialog::Worker(LPVOID p)
{
    TaskingDialog* self = (TaskingDialog*)p;
    //grab data from self, do work, etc, quick thread
    return 0;
}

void TaskingDialog::OnStartThread()
{
    // start a simple worker thread that finishes quickly
    AfxBeginThread(Worker, this);
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for an CWinThread derived class as a worker thread.

Comment: @Goldorak84 Yes, but the reason they gave for wanting to use it was to store important private information. I think it's better to follow the documentation and not derive from CWinThread for a worker thread.

Comment: Here's what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69644x60.aspx) says about worker threads : 

"Creating a worker thread is a relatively simple task. Only two steps are required to get your thread running: implementing the controlling function and starting the thread. It is not necessary to derive a class from CWinThread. You can derive a class if you need a special version of CWinThread, but it is not required for most simple worker threads. You can use CWinThread without modification."